# Proof that for a given prime $a$, there are only finite many carmichael-numbers $N=abc$ with $b,c$ prime

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Please check if the following proof that for every prime $a$, the number of
carmichael numbers $N=abc$ , where $b$ and $c$ are also prime, is finite,
is correct!

First of all, we have

$$a-1|abc-1$$
$$b-1|abc-1$$
$$c-1|abc-1$$

which implies

$$a-1|bc-1$$
$$b-1|ac-1$$
$$c-1|ab-1$$

Considering the last two conditions, we get the equation system

$$ac-1=mb-m$$
$$ab-1=nc-n$$

or

$$mb-ac=m-1$$
$$-ab+nc=n-1$$

Neither $m$ nor $n$ can be disivible by $a$, so $mn-a^2\ne 0$ must hold.

The solution of the system is

$$b=\frac{mn+(a-1)n-a}{mn-a^2}$$
$$c=\frac{mn+(a-1)m-a}{mn-a^2}$$

In particular, we get

$$(a-1)n-a+a^2=(a-1)(a+n)\ge mn-a^2$$
$$(a-1)m-a+a^2=(a-1)(a+m)\ge mn-a^2$$

and finally

$$2a^2-a\ge n(m-a+1)$$
$$2a^2-a\ge m(n-a+1)$$

implying $1\le m,n\le 2a^2-1$

> Is this proof correct ?
>
> Is there a better way to determine all pairs (b,c) ?
>
> If more than $3$ prime factors are allowed, is the number of carmichael numbers containing a fixed prime factor $a$, finite ?

Comment: "neither $m$, $n$ is divisible by $a$ so $mn-a^2\neq 0$" -- $4*9-6^2=0$. I think you wanted to say that $gcd(m,a)=1$.

Comment: $a$ is a prime number!

Comment: Right, I just realized that I missed that part.

Comment: In your counterexample, $gcd(m,a)=1$ would also not hold.

Comment: I mean $gcd(m,a)=1$, which is true from $ac-m(b-1)=1$ even if $a$ is not prime, implies $mn-a^2\ne 0$.

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding:  to get your first inequalities, you're writing the LHS as $(b-1)(mn-a^2)$ and $(c-1)(mn-a^2)$, respectively, and using the fact that $b, c \geq 2$, right?  Is it clear that the denominator $mn-a^2$ is positive?  If it's negative, then the inequality will change directions when you clear denominators.

Comment: For every carmichael number $abc$ with $2<a<b<c$, $mn-a^2$ will be positive.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it now:  $mn = \frac{ac-1}{b-1} \cdot \frac{ab-1}{c-1} = \frac{ac-1}{c-1} \cdot \frac{ab-1}{b-1} > a \cdot a = a^2$.  This of course gives another reason why $mn - a^2$ isn't 0.

Comment: I believe the work you've done is correct, although I haven't yet verified that boundedness of $m$ and $n$ implies that there are only finitely many choices of $b$ and $c$.  (You should be able to recover $b$ and $c$ from $m$ and $n$, but I haven't actually done the calculations...)  However, I think I see a shorter way to show that $m$ and $n$ are bounded.  Namely:  $mn = \frac{ac-1}{b-1} \cdot \frac{ab-1}{c-1} \leq \frac{ac}{b/2} \cdot \frac{ab}{c/2} = 4a^2$.